# call vbsript from .bat or cmd

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I'm trying to call a vbscript using the script below.

Almost everything works fine but seems like it's ignoring the line `WScript "%~dp0\close.vbs"`

close.vbs script closes a dialog box in some application don't know how to do it in cmd.

**Batch Script**

```
FOR %%f IN (*.obj) DO (
    start "C:\Program Files\VCG\MeshLab\meshlab.exe" %%f
    WScript "%~dp0\close.vbs"
    nircmd.exe cmdwait 3000 savescreenshot "%%~nf_OBJ.png"
    taskkill /F /IM meshlab.exe
)
```

**close.vbs**

```
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.AppActivate("Opening Problems")
WScript.Sleep 500
oShell.SendKeys "~"
```

Comment: Hi thanks for quick comment i am running the above code mentioned using .bat. but its not working "  WScript "%~dp0\close.vbs" "

Comment: You should update the question. It's not working isn't enough! Describe what the problem is. E.g. It can't find the script, no output etc.

Comment: i was trying to update the question

Comment: Updated the question please check screen shots has i was unable to upload them here

Comment: I edited your post for you. It's generally considered bad form to post screenshots for code that can be presented directly in the post. Have you tried to execute each line step by step to see if it works outside of the batch file?

Comment: Yes I  tried to execute each line step by step and its works

Comment: So it's possible that it's a timing issue; `matlab.exe` might not be ready before `close.vbs` started. Try putting a sleep before `AppActivate`. It would also be a good idea to change `wscript` to `cscript` in your batch file. One is used for interactive scripts and the other for command line.

Comment: Works like a WScript.Sleep 2000 did the works thank you so much @Dean Ward how to choose you comment has answer :)

Comment: Hi is it possible to add these four lines directly to Batch Script. instead of calling it ?

Answer (score 1):

This was a timing issue. Adding `WScript.Sleep 2000` in vbs script did the job:

```
WScript.Sleep 2000
Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.AppActivate("Opening Problems")
oShell.SendKeys "~"
```

Comment: Hi is it possible to add these four lines directly to Batch Script. instead of calling it ?